# A simple betting game

Tags: probability-theory, game-theory

Consider the following betting game: Two players each have 100 cents to bet. If one player bets more than the other then that player gains a point and the other player loses a point. The goal of the game is to get two points. The betted money is lost from the game entirely (In other words, each player can only bet 100 cents in total).

In principle one could make a finite (expect for the zero loop) game tree for this game and there would be a winning strategy. Now suppose we modify the game, players can bet any real number between zero and one. The game tree is no longer finite. But is there still a winning strategy? What is this strategy?

Naively, you could in principle construct game trees for the finite games, but further subdivide the interval $[0,1]$. Is it plausible to expect some kind of convergence of winning strategies to the continuous case?

I have no knowledge of game theory whatsoever, but I find this an interesting question. Maybe this is well-known, but google didn't find a solution immediately.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't getting any attention. Just try to play the game with someone, I would be happy with some reasoning behind a good strategy for the first round. I found that betting low $(10-20)$ the first round seems to work better than betting high $(40+)$. The reasoning being that you have more money left to react to the opening move.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should play a mixed strategy (randomize), but with what distribution I'm not sure.  Clearly 100 in the first round is bad, as the opponent can play 0, 1,1,1 and win.

Comment: Indeed, I guess distributions will certainly play a role in this game and the weight of 100 should be 0. But other than this explicit value and a intuition about some others, I have no idea how to find such a distribution.
It's certainly not a symmetric distribution , but then again these things are trivial.

Comment: This reminds me of some work on sequential auctions, though the rules are a bit different, and in this case, more stark--you don't care that you lose money (other than strategically) and you only care that you win twice, not what the item is worth to you. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nikdev/pubs/seqauction.pdf

Comment: Looks similar, I will skim through the paper when I have some time. Might be interesting to see which techniques they use. Thank you.

Comment: It might be possible to make some progress considering only markov strategies:  your strategy depends only on the state of the game, which is your score, 1,0,-1, and the two remaining bankrolls, x and y.

Comment: Another approach would be to consider this as a game on a unit square, but I don't know of work that looks at dynamic versions of such games. One approach to the static case that looks interesting is https://statistics.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/KAR%20ONR%2026.pdf